# how to backup Cloudant to mass low cost storage such as AWS Glacier?

Tags: cloudant

One approach organisations sometimes use for backing up Cloudant is to run a standalone instance of CouchDB in their private network or a public network and replicate data from Cloudant to that CouchDB instance.  The CouchDB data can then be exported to mass storage such as Amazon Glacier.

**Questions:**

- What are the steps required to implement this?
- Are there any gotchas to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the approximate steps:

- a server running CouchDB (e.g. in EC2)
- continuous replication from Cloudant --> CouchDB
- periodic (e.g. nightly) cron job to

  - copy the relevant .couch file over somewhere
  - zip it up
  - use AWS command-line tools to put the zipped file on S3
  - use AWS command-line tools to send that S3 file to Glacier

Things to remember:

- Glacier keeps everything unless you say "kill that backup from 30 days ago", so you keep paying for old backups. Best to delete really old stuff
- with continuous replication: if you delete a doc on Cloudant it immediately deletes on your backup (oops)
- restoring from Glacier is a pain, then you can restore it to CouchDB, then you can replicate it to Cloudant.
- Cloudant will not be able to support your CouchDB installation - you will need to support it yourself.